# Parse.com Unity WebPlayer Requires Authentication

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Unity project that I'm trying to build out to Web Player for Facebook. The project previously existed as an Android app and works well with Parse as a backend for high scores.

However, in the web player, I get an authentication pop-up titled "Authentication Required" and the message "A user name and password are being requested by https://api.parse.com. The site says: "Parse"" with Username and Password fields. Entering my Parse credentials didn't seem to work here either. I don't have a Parse User to try either - I just rely on Parse to generate them automatically without passwords. The scores never actually get loaded because this stops the process.

It works in the Editor. Has anyone had a problem similar to this? A search came up empty.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same message after upgrading to Unity 5 with the latest build for parse on the asset store (v. 1.3.5). While it's not a preferable solution downgrading to a previous version build (4.6) the problem does no longer occur.

Comment: I overlooked to think it could have been a Unity 5 issue. The new plugin, v 1.4.0, appears to still have the problem.

I reported the bug to Parse, so hopefully it can be fixed soon.